# Stop changing Order In json parse

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

this is basic string response :

```
response = "[{"prefixtodomid":"Sat17Dec2016103310GMT","todo_title":"task 3 changed","is_done_todo":false,"todo_subtitle_field":"\u00a0","prefix_pro_due_date":"","multicheckbox":false,"project_file_list":""},{"prefixtodomid":"Sat17Dec2016103313GMT","todo_title":"ce","is_done_todo":false,"todo_subtitle_field":"\u00a0","prefix_pro_due_date":"","multicheckbox":false,"project_file_list":""},{"prefixtodomid":"Sat17Dec2016103318GMT","todo_title":"dewdw","is_done_todo":false,"todo_subtitle_field":"\u00a0","prefix_pro_due_date":"","multicheckbox":false,"project_file_list":""},{"prefixtodomid":"Sat17Dec2016103321GMT","todo_title":"task 4","is_done_todo":false,"todo_subtitle_field":"\u00a0","prefix_pro_due_date":"","multicheckbox":false,"project_file_list":""},{"prefixtodomid":"Sat17Dec2016181953GMT","todo_title":"task 5","is_done_todo":false,"todo_subtitle_field":"\u00a0","prefix_pro_due_date":"","multicheckbox":false,"project_file_list":{"43":"http:\/\/example\/intra\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/11\/1project.png","26":"http:\/\/example\/intra\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/11\/2016--\u2039-Le-Blog-OSD-\u2014-WordPress_437.png"}},{"prefixtodomid":"Sat17Dec2016181957GMT","todo_title":"cewcwcwecw","todo_subtitle_field":"\u00a0","project_file_list":{"26":"http:\/\/example\/intra\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/11\/2016-10-16-15_26_04-Unyson-\u2039-Le-Blog-OSD-\u2014-WordPress_437.png"}}]"
```

i parsed it to json like :

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( response );
```

now i am looping through this :

```
for (var i = 0; i<Object.keys(obj).length; i++) { 
                (function(index){

                    var haveimage = obj[i].project_file_list;

                    if(haveimage){
                        // other logic
                    }

                })(i); // pass the value of i
            }
```

here haveimage is showing image always in order of id of image , even if we change order in response string , parseJSON method just change order by id again , is there any solution to overcome this ?

if not is there anything else i can use instead of parseJSON ?

Thank you :)

Comment: I have never noticed this behavior before... have you tried JSON.parse()?

Comment: Your json will parse to an array of objects. You don't use `Object.keys()` on an array

Comment: @charlietfl thank you for reply , sorry , could you give more details , i am checking is it's array in logic by using  splice method , but thing is that array itself is sorted after JSON.parse , i am not sure what to do with .keys after parsing or even before .

Comment: @Steve yup , already checked , it's same .

Comment: Since *obj* is an array, `Object.keys(obj).length` is equivalent to `obj.length`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.

You can use array to maintain the order:

```
[
   {
      "43":"http:\/\/example\/intra\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/11\/1project.png"
   },
   {
      "26":"http:\/\/example\/intra\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/11\/2016--\u2039-Le-Blog-OSD-\u2014-WordPress_437.png"
   }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for response , i think this can be used . can you give me some quick info on how to create array from my response ? i tried using split function but it's causing issue , since i can't split with , or ,} , there are unwanted characters , is there other function for that ? thanks again .